# Differences between Traversing/Binding/Fold-Binding Effects in Purescript

Tags: purescript

I've been trying to wrap my head around this, I've written four functions that I expect should run the same, I'm curious why they're different.

```hs
toEffect :: Tuple Int String -> Effect Unit
toEffect (Tuple i strng) = 
  log $ append (show i <> ": ") $
  statefulPuzzleToString $ 
  selectFirstLadderBruteForce $
  parsePuzzle strng

main1 :: Effect Unit
main1 = (toEffect $ Tuple 1 $ fromMaybe "" $ hardestBoardStringsX11 !! 0) >>=
  (\_ -> toEffect $ Tuple 2 $ fromMaybe "" $ hardestBoardStringsX11 !! 1) >>=
  (\_ -> toEffect $ Tuple 3 $ fromMaybe "" $ hardestBoardStringsX11 !! 2) >>=
  (\_ -> toEffect $ Tuple 4 $ fromMaybe "" $ hardestBoardStringsX11 !! 3)
  -- ... Pattern could continue for all 11 boards
  
main2 :: Effect Unit
main2 = do
  toEffect $ Tuple 1 $ fromMaybe "" $ hardestBoardStringsX11 !! 0
  toEffect $ Tuple 2 $ fromMaybe "" $ hardestBoardStringsX11 !! 1
  toEffect $ Tuple 3 $ fromMaybe "" $ hardestBoardStringsX11 !! 2
  toEffect $ Tuple 4 $ fromMaybe "" $ hardestBoardStringsX11 !! 3
  -- ... Pattern could continue for all 11 boards

main3 :: Effect Unit
main3 = foldl 
  (\acc new -> acc >>= \_ -> new)
  (pure unit)
  effects
  where
    effects :: Array (Effect Unit)
    effects = map toEffect $ mapWithIndex Tuple hardestBoardStringsX11

main4 :: Effect Unit
main4 = traverse_ toEffect $ mapWithIndex Tuple hardestBoardStringsX11
```

For the first two, the console appears to display each effect as it happens. There's maybe upwards of a 1/2second delay between log statements. I'd be extremely surprised to see these behave differently as I understand that the do notation in main2 is just syntactic sugar for what was written in `main1`

The second two appear log their statements simultaneously.

I'm not entirely certain about `main4`, but I feel pretty confident that `main3` really aught to behave the same as the first two.

Any insight into what's happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `main3` and `main4` behave that way for the same reason, and the reason is the difference between *evaluation* and *execution*.

---

When you have a value of type `Effect a`, which represents some effect that produces `a`, presumably you got that value from somewhere. Let's say:

```
myEffect = makeMeAnEffect "foo"
```

This value has been *evaluated* inside `makeMeAnEffect`, but hasn't yet been *executed*. Here, "evaluation" means making whatever computation is necessary to produce a value of type `Effect a`. Creating this value may involve some computation - e.g. multiplying numbers, traversing strings, adding matrices. That's all "evaluation".

But the result of evaluation is a "description" of what should happen when the effect is *executed*. Here "execution" means "running" the effect, making happen whatever action it describes.

Evaluation and execution are technically separate concepts. Many languages conflate them, but pure functional languages, such as PureScript and Haskell, maintain a strict separation: first you create the description of what should happen ("evaluation"), and then "run" that description ("execution").

This distinction is very important in practice: "evaluation" is pure, which means it's completely unobservable except for its result, and so the compiler can do whatever it wants with it - e.g. optimize, roll/unroll, or even completely drop, - as long as its result stays the same. "Execution", on the other hand, has to be carried out in the exact way that the programmer has specified it, because its whole point is to produce effects, so messing with it will have observable consequences.

---

In your particular case, in the body of `toEffect`, evaluation is everything that happens after `log $`. All those calls to `append`, `selectFirstLadderBruteForce`, and so on, - all of that is "evaluation". None of that is effectful. You're performing some computation in order to figure out what sort of effect you're going to create.

And then, once you did all that computation, you pass the result of it to `log`, and that makes you an `Effect Unit`, which is a "description of what should happen". And in this particular case, "what should happen" is very small - just write a single string to the console.

---

And now, finally, we can get to the difference between `main1`/`main2` and `main3`/`main4`.

In `main1` and `main2`, you're creating each next effect only after the first one has been executed. So evaluation and execution "overlap", so to speak: first you do fist evaluation, create fist effect, then you run it, and then, only after it's done running, you move on to doing the second evaluation and creating the second effect. And so on. Since the expensive part (in your case) is evaluation, each next execution ends up delayed by however much time the next evaluation takes.

In `main3` and `main4`, on the other hand, you do evaluation first, creating all effects at once by calling `map toEffect` on an array, and only then you proceed to execute them one by one. And since, again, evaluation (in your case) is the expensive part, and all of it is happening at the beginning, the execution is not delayed. Each effect is very small (just print to console), so they all execute very quickly.

---

If you really want to prevent the next evaluation from happening until the previous execution is done, you can do this trick: add a `pure unit` at the beginning of `toEffect` like so:

```
toEffect (Tuple i strng) = do
  pure unit

  log $ append (show i <> ": ") $
  statefulPuzzleToString $ 
  selectFirstLadderBruteForce $
  parsePuzzle strng
```

This will make sure that the second line doesn't start *evaluating* until the first line has *executed*, thus making each evaluation happen only right before its respective execution.

---

And finally, another fun fact: in Haskell the same program would work differently, because Haskell is lazy. When asked to do an evaluation, it doesn't do it right away, instead just "remembering" that it's been asked to. And only when the evaluation's result is actually necessary (which would happen on execution), will it be performed.

PureScript, on the other hand, is strict, which means it will always compute everything right away. In this particular case, it means it will compute the whole `append` etc. series of calls before it can pass their result to `log`.

Comment: Thanks, that all makes sense to me; or at least jives with the intuition I've been developing about monads.

Comment: Wonderful explanation! I learn a lot from your insightful, deep and clear answers. Thanks a lot Fyodor!